# Do MediaWiki extensions BlueSpice and Semantic play well together?

Tags: mediawiki, semantic-web

I'm currently running BlueSpice and came across [Semantic MediaWiki](https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Semantic_MediaWiki) that looks interesting such as its calendar capabilities.  However, I'm wondering how well they work together.  I found this [2012 talk](https://semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/SMWCon_Fall_2012/BlueSpice) which states:

> There are some challenges, though, to a deeper integration of both systems, among them duplication of functionality, a very different code base and different approaches to user interface design.

What is the status in 2015?  Do these still work together well?  Are the overlaps still prevalent?

Comment: BlueSpice is a collection of many extensions and SemanticMediaWiki has many sub-extensions as well. What sort of features are you interested in?

Comment: @Nemo I'm using the BlueSpice collection of extensions and was wishing to add the calendar capabilities from Semantic.

Comment: I do not use the calendar capabilities from Semantic but plenty of other features. I have not experienced any issues. In fact, I was not aware of any overlaps beforehand, so I just started and added the Semantic extensions to my BlueSpice. Everything works well.